# Is elliptic curve suitable for using in ECDLP?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithms

I have elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + x + 1$ over $GF(101)$ . I need to find order and decide if it is suitable for using in elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem me.

I tried to find order, and I think it should be 105, can someone help me, if it is correct?

The second question, if it is suitable for using in ECDLP. I need to mention at least two reasons. I think this elliptic curve it is not suitable, because it has small order. But I don't know about other reasons. Could someone help me with this?

edit: Why the comments disappeared?